# Multidimensional Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, multidimensional-array, grid, dimensions

I have to implement a grid file. Requirement is to build grid files for 1-32 dimension. like i may need to build one grid file with 4 dimensions, one with 32 dimensions etc.

Please suggest a suitable data structure which may support grid directory and can be used for 1-32 Dimensions inclusive.

Thanks.

Comment: Even the string theory didn't have that many dimensions last time I read about it...

Comment: What do you mean with `grid directory`? Is that supposed to be some kind of index in front of the binary data?

Comment: Are you asking for the file format, the in-program data structure, the code to (de)serialize one to the other, or all three? What are you storing in your grid, and what operations do you need to perform on it? Help us out, make this a real question.

Comment: A 32-dimensional grid of 1-byte cells with just 2 cells along each dimension would take up 4 GB.

Answer (score -1):

The Boost Multidimensional Array Library 
(Boost.MultiArray)

> Synopsis
>
> The Boost Multidimensional Array Library provides a class template for
>   multidimensional arrays, as well as semantically equivalent adaptors
>   for arrays of contiguous data. The classes in this library implement a
>   common interface, formalized as a generic programming concept. The
>   interface design is in line with the precedent set by the C++ Standard
>   Library containers. Boost MultiArray is a more efficient and
>   convenient way to express N-dimensional arrays than existing
>   alternatives (especially the std::vector> formulation
>   of N-dimensional arrays). The arrays provided by the library may be
>   accessed using the familiar syntax of native C++ arrays. Additional
>   features, such as resizing, reshaping, and creating views are
>   available (and described below).

source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: -1: You copy-pasted text about general topics when the question is about serialization.

Comment: To be fair, I thought the question was asking for the data structure, not the (de)serialization - it's pretty ambiguous though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter the question is about multidimensional arrays, topic covered by the Boost library.